# ROC curve based on means and variances of controls and cases

Tags: r, roc

Does anyone know of an R package (or any other statistical freeware or just a piece of code) that lets you plot a smooth ROC curve knowing only the means and variances of the control and case groups? That is, one that doesn't require a dataset with specific classifier values and test outcomes. I found a couple of online graph plotters that do just that:
https://kennis-research.shinyapps.io/ROC-Curves/ ,
http://arogozhnikov.github.io/2015/10/05/roc-curve.html 
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need any fancy package for this. You can just use simple probability functions in base R.

```
m1 <- 0
m2 <- 2
v1 <- 4
v2 <- 4

range <- seq(-10, 10, length.out=200)

d1<-pnorm(range, m1, sd=sqrt(v1))
d2<-pnorm(range, m2, sd=sqrt(v2))

tpr <- 1-d2
fpr <- 1-d1

plot(fpr, tpr, xlim=0:1, ylim=0:1, type="l")
abline(0,1, lty=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The reason why I asked about a specific package is that I was hoping I could use it (to generate an object) for further calculations, e.g. AUC and cutoff. I understand that these too can be calculated analytically with just the core functions. But a package could make it easier. In pROC you can build a rocobject and plot a smoothened ROC curve if you provide means and sd's but you still need a large enough dataset to begin with. Perhaps I should have made my question more clear.